# Stuck Molex Connector (Dead PSU)

Tags: connector, repair

I have a very stubborn molex connector on a FF800 board and I am hesitant to use force on it.
I have been asking for suggestions to coax the detent out of the socket but have had little success. I thought of using a hair dryer and maybe a scalpel. The person who previously did this repair has closed and next closest shop is out of province.

Anyone have any tips for this kind of situation with little clearance?

https://imagebin.ca/v/6FBICgToUayS

https://imagebin.ca/v/6FBIJYLT8q28

Answer (score 1):

Using 99% alcohol the connection finally came loose.

credit: Owen Osborne